# Changing iframe content with flash buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I am trying to change iframe src from a flash button which is located outside from iframe

here is my code

```
this.contact.onRelease = function() {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("page2.html", target="myframe") );
};
```

but this is not working

Comment: Google `ExternalInterface`.

Comment: Looks more like ActionScript 2 (`this.contact.onRelease`). Are you getting any errors on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change the iframe content without the `ExternalInterface` but you are also restricted to your own domain I think. You were almost right with your code.
I'm not sure if the `this.contact.onRelease` is going to work but the `navigateToURL` should be like this:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("page2.html"), "myframe");
```

You were assigning the target to the `URLRequest` and also the target is just a string, so without `target=..`.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()